# I can't make this in to a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

I can't make a for loop out of this
All those while loops should be in a single for loop
(this is a part of a class, that's why self is used)

```
self.task1 = ""
self.task2 = ""
self.task3 = ""
self.task4 = ""
self.task5 = ""
self.tasks = [self.task1, self.task2, self.task3, self.task4, self.task5]

while True:
    num1 = random.randint(0, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(0, 10)
    if num1 + num2 <= 10:
        break
self.task1 = "{} + {} =".format(num1, num2)

while True:
    num1 = random.randint(0, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(0, 10)
    if num1 + num2 <= 10:
        break
self.task2 = "{} + {} =".format(num1, num2)

while True:
    num1 = random.randint(0, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(0, 10)
    if num1 + num2 <= 10:
        break
self.task3 = "{} + {} =".format(num1, num2)

while True:
    num1 = random.randint(0, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(0, 10)
    if num1 + num2 <= 10:
        break
self.task4 = "{} + {} =".format(num1, num2)

while True:
    num1 = random.randint(0, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(0, 10)
    if num1 + num2 <= 10:
        break
self.task5 = "{} + {} =".format(num1, num2)
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
for task in self.tasks:
    while True:
    num1 = random.randint(0, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(0, 10)
    if num1 + num2 <= 10:
        break
task = "{} + {} =".format(num1, num2)
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Please add more details, like the error that you are facing.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not helpful. Please explain what exactally doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate method:

```
for task in self.tasks:
    task = randomTask()

...

def randomTask():
    while True:
        num1 = random.randint(0, 10)
        num2 = random.randint(0, 10)
        if num1 + num2 <= 10:
            break
    return "{} + {} =".format(num1, num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to indent the code inside a loop :

```
for task in self.tasks:
    while True:
        num1 = random.randint(0, 10)
        num2 = random.randint(0, 10)
        if num1 + num2 <= 10:
            break
    task = "{} + {} =".format(num1, num2)
```